# What is the focus of the statement included below

Tags: grammar

What is the focus of this statement:

> "You will be responsible for developing and executing marketing
> initiatives to enhance brand awareness, increase customer acquisition,
> and drive revenue growth."

Does the statement put focus on the part "You will be responsible for developing and executing marketing initiatives" and thus these initiatives will "enhance brand awareness, increase customer acquisition, and drive revenue growth."?

or is it more:

> You will be responsible for (all) of the following:
>
> - developing and executing marketing initiatives
> - enhancing brand awareness
> - increasing customer acquisition
> - driving revenue growth

Comment: The two interpretations are not that different in the end. Since your campaign should produce 3 results, you will be expected to handle all 4 bullets over time.

Comment: I'd say this is more appropriate on Writing.SE, which looks at how communication is analysed (including relevant metalanguage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The person will be responsible for developing and executing marketing initiatives. Those initiatives should accomplish things like enhancing brand awareness, increasing customer acquisition, and driving revenue growth. The focus is on "marketing initiatives", with the intended outcomes listed after. The focus is not really on the outcomes directly - the person is not expected to drive revenue growth by inventing a new product or spearheading an acquisition, for example. They are not in general responsible for all of the bullet points you list, but rather only as they relate to the first bullet of marketing.

Comment: This is the correct analysis of the structure of the sentence, but one can't help wondering what exactly is the point of listing the three aims of 'developing and executing marketing initiatives'. Has any employer ever hired someone to develop and execute marketing initiatives that do not accomplish these aims?

Comment: @jsw29 I don't find it unreasonable to list a few examples of the employee's responsibility, the term "marketing initiatives" can cover a pretty wide breadth. It would be possible to hire someone to market to *existing* customers, who would not be responsible for acquiring new customers, and a marketing hire for a shrinking industry might not be expected to drive revenue growth.